# does the server generate both the private and public keys?

Tags: https, rsa

While surfing the web through a browser, when does the server send the public key to the client? or is it the other way around?
I was reading a response to a questions earlier and wanted to comment but due to my lack in reputation, I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can answer your question:

When visiting a website using 'https' or 'http over tls/ssl',
the key exchange works something like this:\

- The Client sends a "Client Hello" to the server.
- The server generates both the *public* and *private key*.
- The Server answers with "Server Hello" and sends the *public key* to the Client.
- The Client encrypts a so-called *pre-master secret* with this *public key* and sends it to the server.
- The Server can then decrypt this *pre-master secret* with his private key
- Both the Server and the Client calculate a *master secret* from the *pre-master secret*.
- Both the Server and the Client calculate the *session key* (for a symmetric encryption) from this secret.

Now the Client and Server can communicate with this *session key*.

Reference:

- [HTTPS - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)
- [TLS - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_1.0,_2.0,_and_3.0)